# delete games when user is deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-key-relationship, destroy

In my web application users have the ability to upload games which are then associated to each user by a user_id column in the games table.

What I want to do now is whenever a user deletes their profile then the games associated with them are also erased.

I am wondering how I would go about doing this?

In the destroy method the users controller I currently have:

```
def destroy
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
@user.destroy

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to users_url }
  format.json { head :ok }
end
end
```

Would it be some sort of @user.id == @game.user_id.destroy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add :dependent => :destroy when you declare the association in the model:

`has_many :games, :dependent => :destroy`